# At which point can a power supply can rate itself at a certain current

Tags: power-supply, current, standard

Say if you have a power supply rated "9V @ 5A". Typically the open circuit voltage is slightly greater than the voltage rated, possibly 9.7V or something and levels off when drawing current (EDIT: levels off to nearly exactly 9V).

At the 5A at which it was rated, how much can the voltage output drop below 9V to be able to rate itself at "9V @ 5A".

Comment: First, a good power supply will vary MUCH less than you think is normal - 10's of millivolts is not unreasonable, and some will do better than that (at a price, of course). And generally, a current-limited supply will start to drop its voltage exactly at the limiting current, so you've got things backwards. And go read about foldback current limiting.

Comment: Usually, standards get set for manufacturers to make these claims.

Comment: I'm just pissed that I ended up with said power supply. Coz when I loaded 10ohm power resistor to it, it drops to 8.6V. I had an earlier 9V @ 5A power supply that arrived months ago (and if memory serves passed the test, but not sure til 5A), but I busted it. Coz I desoldered the transformer to measure the gauge of the output winding, put it away and then forgot to resolder. Then I absent mindedly plugged it back in. I don't know if I busted the NMOS or optocoupler or the small IC.

Comment: No, there are no standards. There are only specifications. Granted, it sounds like you've got a broken supply, but if you agree that you've broken something in it, I don't see how you can be pissed at it. At yourself, maybe, but not at it.

Comment: Power supplies don't rate themselves. People rate power supplies.

Answer (score 3):

A well-designed 9 Volt 5 Amp regulated power supply should deliver 9.0 Volts, and the output voltage should only vary a few millivolts with load currents from 0 to 5 Amps.

The 5 Amp rating means that the supply can deliver up to that current without damage or over-heating.

Cheap unregulated wall-wart supplies should deliver up to the rated current while remaining "close" to the specified voltage and often deliver significantly more than the rated voltage at low loads.  Only the maker knows what "close" means.